# Vuejs IndexedDB: I have to log in twice

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, indexeddb, localforage

For 3 weeks now I have had an issue:
I integrated IndexedDb into an existing VueJs project using `localforage` and `vuex-persist` like so:

```js
//within store/index.js
...
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist';
import localForage from 'localforage';

const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({
    key: 'KEY_HERE',
  storage: localForage,
  asyncStorage: true,
});

export default new Vuex.Store({
      plugins:[vuexLocal.plugin],
      modules: {...},
      strict: process.env.DEV,
})
```

This works fine when storing and receiving data using the `await store.restored` promise as recommended [here](https://dev.to/siujoeng_lau/persist-vuex-state-between-page-reloads-with-localstorage-and-indexeddb-2g21)

**Now for the issue:**

I use a key within the indexedDB entry to store some authorization values like username, region, and others and I use that to check for authentication.
When I login for the first time **after signout**, **IndexedDB weirdly updates then clears** such that by the time I refresh the page or re-route to the dashboard, all is gone and I am redirected to the login page.

Supprisingly when I login this second time it goes through! Here's my code:

```js
//signout
 store.dispatch("auth/logout")
    .then(async () => {
                let currState = await localforage.getItem('KEY_HERE')
                currState.auth = {/*auth defaults*/}

                localforage.setItem('KEY_HERE',currState)
                 .then((val) => {
                    //...Notify and reroute to login
                    window.location.href = '/login'
                })
                .catch(err => console.log('Signout error: ', err))

})
```

```js
//login
 login({ commit }, credentials) {
    return new FetchIo('/auth/login/', false, 'login') //normal api call
        .post(JSON.stringify({"email":credentials.email,"password":credentials.password,}))
            .then((data) => {
                  ...
                   if (data){
                        let {tokens, ...userData} = data
                         commit('SET_USER', userData)
                            
                      }
                    return Promise.resolve(data)
            })
            
  },
```

I still don't understand why the login passes the second time. I have tried several options/theories:

- Credentials not beign correctly reset on signout
- Deleting the key during signout
- Re-initialising it before login

Nothing has worked so far. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!